# setInterval: Why isn't it resetting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Why doesn't this code work to turn off setInterval?  I click an element to start it, and it begins fine (fading in and out a div #content on 5 second intervals).  I click an element to stop it, and it just continues to fade in and out on the week=current, even though it loads the proper week initially.

It does not matter whether I separate the function from the jQuery encapsulation.  Any help appreciated.

```
  $out .= '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";
  $out .= '$(document).ready(function () {'."\n";
  $out .= '  $("span.archives").click(function () {'."\n";
  $out .= '    $("#content").load("update.php?week=" + this.id);'."\n";
  $out .= '    if (this.id == \'current\') {'."\n";
  $out .= '      StartStop(\'on\');'."\n";
  $out .= '    } else {'."\n";
  $out .= '      StartStop(\'off\');'."\n";
  $out .= '    }'."\n";
  $out .= '  });'."\n";

  $out .= '  function StartStop(txt) {'."\n";
  $out .= '    if (txt == \'on\') {'."\n";
  $out .= '      var refresh = setInterval(function() {'."\n";
  $out .= '        $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {'."\n";
  $out .= '          $("#content").load("update.php?week=current", function() {'."\n";
  $out .= '            $("#content").delay(250).fadeIn("slow");'."\n";
  $out .= '          });'."\n";
  $out .= '        });'."\n";
  $out .= '      }, 5000);'."\n";
  $out .= '    } else {'."\n";
  $out .= '      clearInterval(refresh);'."\n";
  $out .= '    }'."\n";
  $out .= '  }'."\n";
  $out .= '});'."\n";
  $out .= '</script>'."\n";
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you store the JavaScript code as a string in PHP? It is very hard to debug (and maintain).

Comment: Even if you do store it in code, PHP string literals can span multiple lines: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't really done any optimizations yet. It's for a Wordpress plugin, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refresh` is defined **locally** within `StartStop`, its value isn't saved between calls to `StartStop`.
Try defining it outside of it, for example:

```
var refresh;

function StartStop(txt) {
    refresh = setInterval(/* ... */);
}
```

Also, you may want to clear the previous `refresh` before creating a new one:

```
if (txt == 'on') {
    if(refresh) clearInterval(refresh);
    refresh = setInterval(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: @daveycroqet - No problem, happy to help! By the way, thanks for pushing my reputation above 30K `:)`